# Getting US COVID-19 booster certificate if first 2 doses were abroad?

Tags: usa, covid-19

I got the first 2 Pfizer doses in Israel more than 10 months ago, and would like to get the booster here in the US given that I live here.

Will I get a US certificate if I only get the booster here? I'm afraid of ending up without a certificate neither in Israel nor in US.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel.

Comment: You'll get a vaccine card with your booster date, but it won't include the dates from your initial shot.

Comment: Can you contact your primary healthcare provider in Israel and/or the US and ask them if they will update your records?